# Change `ggplot` label color by conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a question about changing color for `geom_text` & `geom_label` base on a condition.

**Expected out put**

- Data label has `color = blue` for 2021, `color = grey` for 2020
- Gap label is red when `negative` and green when `positive`

**Data**

```
data <-  tibble(Factor = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
   Score = c(90, 85, 85, 90),
   Year = c("2020", "2020", "2021", "2021"))
```

**Data transform**

```
   df_2 = data %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = Year, names_prefix = "Year", values_from = Score) %>% 
     mutate(gap = Year2021 - Year2020) %>% 
     select(Factor, gap)
```

**Plot**

```
data %>% 
  left_join(df_2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Factor, y = Score, fill = Year)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label=Score), 
            position=position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            vjust=-0.40) +
  geom_label(aes(y = 100, label = ifelse(Year == 2021, gap, NA_character_)), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105))
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**Expected out put**

- `85 & 90 = blue` for 2021, `90 & 85 = grey` for 2020
- `-5 = red` and `5 = green`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second option would be to use a manual scale for the text and bar colors. For the labels we could use the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales for the same aesthetic. Doing so we could add a second fill scale:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Factor, y = Score, fill = Year)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Score, color = Year),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
    vjust = -0.40
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(aesthetics = c("fill", "color"), values = c("2021" = "blue", "2020" = "grey")) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_label(aes(y = 100, label = ifelse(Year == 2021, gap, NA_character_), fill = gap > 0), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "red", "TRUE" = "green")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 105)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
data <- data.frame(
  Factor = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  Score = c(90, 85, 85, 90),
  Year = c("2020", "2020", "2021", "2021")
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_2 <- data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, names_prefix = "Year", values_from = Score) %>%
  mutate(gap = Year2021 - Year2020) %>%
  select(Factor, gap)

dat <- data %>%
  left_join(df_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally assign the colors to the aesthetics using `case_when`. You can use the following code:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data <-  tibble(Factor = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
                Score = c(90, 85, 85, 90),
                Year = c("2020", "2020", "2021", "2021"))

df_2 = data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, names_prefix = "Year", values_from = Score) %>% 
  mutate(gap = Year2021 - Year2020) %>% 
  select(Factor, gap)

df <- data %>% left_join(df_2)
#> Joining, by = "Factor"
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = Factor, y = Score, fill = Year)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge') +
  geom_text(df, mapping = aes(label=Score, color = Year),
            color = case_when(
              df$Score == 85 & df$Year == 2021 | df$Score == 90 & df$Year == 2021 ~ "blue",
              df$Score == 85 & df$Year == 2020 | df$Score == 90 & df$Year == 2020 ~ "grey",
            ),
            position=position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            vjust=-0.40) +
  geom_label(data = df, mapping = aes(y = 100, label = ifelse(Year == 2021, gap, NA_character_)),
             fill = case_when(
               df$gap == -5 ~ "red",
               df$gap == 5 ~ "green"
             ), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,105)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You could simplify a bit by using a manual scale for the text and bars as I did in my approach. Anyway +1.

Comment: @stefan, yes you are right! Nice approach using ggnewscale.

Comment: Thanks so much Quinten for the solution :)